# Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#

i get the following error:

> Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

The error occurs at the following code:

```
 case 11:
                {
                    ButtonBase buttonBase2 = (ButtonBase)target;
                    WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler<RoutedEventHandler>(new Func<RoutedEventHandler, EventRegistrationToken>(buttonBase2, ButtonBase.add_Click), new Action<EventRegistrationToken>(buttonBase2, ButtonBase.remove_Click), new RoutedEventHandler(this.RemoveTrack));
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compile-time error. And from MSDN [WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh138484(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
```

If you are to add/remove event handlers to the Click event, use the [`+=` and `-=` operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

```
buttonBase2.Click += this.RemoveTrack;
```

and

```
buttonBase2.Click -= this.RemoveTrack;
```